# Why did Kaluza need to invent a new theory to unify general relativity and electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein, unified-theories

Wikipedia (and many other sources) say that by extending the number of spacetime dimensions from four to five, [Kaluza–Klein theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory) unifies general relativity and electromagnetism into a single theory. But why do need to do anything as complicated as adding a new dimension? It's conceptually very easy to write down [Maxwell's equations in curved spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime) without doing anything nearly as fancy. How is this any less "unified?"

In the quantum context, a compact extra dimension gives a natural justification for the quantization of electric charge, but Kaluza's original theory was entirely classical.

Comment: Because it allows for EM to arise from a metric theory in five dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Unification" usually means that you have a *single* theory - not two coupled theories (and is also not a *formally* defined notion, so you'll find some people calling theories "unified" that others wouldn't). Maxwellian electrodynamics in curved space is two coupled theories in the sense that it is "electromagnetism + gravity/general relativity", or in the sense that it has *two* dynamical fields - the metric and the electromagnetic potential.

Kaluza-Klein theory in five dimensions is just gravity, the only dynamical field is the metric, which splits into the four-dimensional metric and vector potential, hence it is unified. Unification is *not* about the theory being necessarily *simple* or "not fancy", it's just about there being a *single* dynamical field from which the multiple dynamical fields being unified arise through an arbitrarily complicated process.

Comment: Eh, I see what you're getting at, but your distinction between one and two fields seems fairly arbitrary. The metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ in $D$ spacetime dimensions could reasonably be thought of as one field, or $D(D+1)/2$ different fields, or $D^2$ different fields respecting $D(D-1)/2$ constraints, depending on how you count.

Comment: The metric and EM field-strength tensors are *formally* "unified" into one Lorentz-covariant tensor, but this object violates the "spirit" of a tensor - you can't transformation the spacetime coordinates in a way that mixes them together, because doing so would violate the cylinder assumption on which the whole theory rests. By only allowing coordinate transformations within the two sectors, you effectively break the one tensor into two coupled tensors.

Comment: Note that Kaluza-Klein theory also isn't "unified" in the technical sense of Grand Unified Theory, because the gauge group isn't a compact simple Lie group.

Comment: @tparker Well, I see what *you're* getting at, but I can't help what people call "unification" in this context. I'm fairly certain that what I wrote here is the intended meaning of "Kaluza-Klein theory unifies gravity and electromagnetism", no matter how consistent it is with other usages of "unification" or how useful/non-arbitrary the notion is to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The motivation is simple, and it's an argument that I came up with when I was 17, when I "independently discovered" the idea of tacking on an extra dimension to incorporate electromagnetism. The term "independently discovered" means more precisely, "coming up with the idea maybe a decade after seeing reruns of [The Borderland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borderland) episode of The Outer Limits". That episode really makes a lasting impression on you, when you're a kid. YouTube put it up ad-supported for free [cued into the action here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgJAC5Nf3Wo&t=1831s).

This is the argument I came up with at the time, to motivate the extension. To some degree it's also reflected by Bleecker [Gauge Theory And Variational Principles](https://books.google.com/books?id=w3z1DAAAQBAJ). You want to somehow add electromagnetism alongside gravity into the "already geometrized theory" bin, to turn all of dynamics and field theory into applied geometry, but you run into an immediate problem.

One of the main talking points of a geometrized theory is the property advanced by it that two bodies that start in the same initial condition - the same position and momentum - will travel along the same trajectory at the same rate: *The Equivalence Principle*. This is not true for electrically charged bodies. Two bodies with opposite charges that start in the same place and have the same initial momentum will move on different trajectories and/or at different rates in the presence of a non-zero electromagnetic field. There's no Equivalence Principle for electromagnetism, per se.

The only way to force the Equivalence Principle to continue being true is to surmise that the charge, somehow, relates to motion in yet another unseen direction not covered by the three dimensions of space. That means it's another component of momentum. So, the natural thing to do is tack on another dimension, plug it into the geodesic equation and see what happens when you extract out the part that's associated with the extra dimension. You get something that looks just like the Lorentz force law cranked out alongside the geodesic equation.

At that point, all the pieces start falling into place. The gauge transforms of electromagnetic theory are analogous to coordinate transforms in General Relativity. The gauge invariance becomes analogous to invariance under coordinate transforms, so it is natural to treat gauge transforms as just being coordinate transforms in the extra direction provided by the extra dimension.

The metric and affine connection subsume the electromagnetic potential. The curvature tensor subsumes the field strength. The Einstein-Hilbert action subsumes the Maxwell-Lorentz action, and the pieces (mostly) come together like pieces in a puzzle. Bleecker does a derivation that is suitable for gauge theory, where the underlying geometry is the [principal bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle) for the gauge field. For the Standard Model, which has 8 + 3 + 1 gauge dimensions that would be 16 dimensions, in all, for the geometry. This is overkill. You can also do something similar with [Homogeneous Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space).

The gauge group acts "transitively" on each of the extra dimensions on a principal bundle, at any point for the underlying base spacetime. For a homogeneous space, in contrast, it acts in a reduced fashion, so that the effective group is only a quotient of the gauge group. The smallest number of dimensions for a homogeneous space for the Standard Model that incorporates all the distinctive properties of the different types of leptons and quarks without conflating things is 7. Witten showed that, I think, in the 1980's. I don't have a reference handy. Nor do I know how robust that result is against dropping the assumption that there are no right neutrinos or left anti-neutrinos (which was the going assumption in the Standard Model at the time). So, for the Standard Model, the smallest number of dimensions that gives you a "Kaluza-Klein" like geometry is at least 11.

For electromagnetism, there is no distinction between a principal bundle and homogeneous space, since there's only one extra dimension. The only reduction of such a principal bundle would be to the base space-time manifold itself; i.e. no extra dimensions at all. So, electromagnetism Kaluza-Klein is with a principal bundle.

The extra dimension is practically already sticking out like a sore thumb when you write the dynamics for a moving charge in the following way:
$$\frac{d( + e)}{dt} = -∇(e(φ - ·)),\quad \frac{d(E + eφ)}{dt} = \frac{∂}{∂t}(e(φ - ·)),\quad \frac{de}{dt} = 0,$$
where
$$ = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 - ||^2/c^2}},\quad E = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1 - ||^2/c^2}},\quad  = \frac{d}{dt}$$
where $ = \left(p_x, p_y, p_z\right)$ is the momentum of the body, $m$ its mass, $ = (x, y, z)$ its position, $φ$ the electric potential and $ = \left(A_x, A_y, A_z\right)$ the vector potential. The partial derivatives on the right are to be taken only with respect to the coordinate dependence $(,t)$ in $(,φ)$.

First, convert to proper time, which I'll denote by $s$, with
$$\frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - ||^2/c^2}}.$$
Then, we may rewrite this as:
$$
\frac{d( + e)}{ds} = \frac{∂}{∂}\left(e\left(·\frac{d}{ds} - φ\frac{dt}{ds}\right)\right),\quad -\frac{d(E + eφ)}{ds} = \frac{∂}{∂t}\left(e\left(·\frac{d}{ds} - φ\frac{dt}{ds}\right)\right),\quad \frac{de}{ds} = 0,\\
 = m\frac{d}{ds},\quad -E = -mc^2\frac{dt}{ds}.
$$

Next, set up the following components:
$$
η_{ij} = δ_{ij},\quad η_{i4} = 0 = η_{4j},\quad η_{44} = -c^2\quad(i,j=1,2,3),\\
 = \left(p_1,p_2,p_3\right),\quad p_4 = -E,\quad  = \left(A_1,A_2,A_3\right),\quad A_4 = -φ,\quad  = \left(x^1,x^2,x^3\right),\quad x^4 = t,
$$
where $δ_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta, defined as usual as $δ_{ij} = 1$ if $i = j$ and $δ_{ij} = 0$ if $i ≠ j$. Then, using the Einstein summation convention (of summing over repeated indices, over the applicable range of the indices), we have:
$$
\frac{d(p_μ + e A_μ)}{ds} = \frac{∂}{∂x^μ}\left(eA_ν\frac{dx^ν}{ds}\right),\quad \frac{de}{ds} = 0,\quad p_μ = m η_{μν} \frac{dx^ν}{ds}.
$$
Greek indices, (e.g. $μ$, $ν$) are to take on the range $1,2,3,4$.

The components $η_{μν}$ are those of the Minkowski metric and the associated line element is:
$$η_{μν} dx^μ dx^ν = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 - c^2 dt^2.$$

Now, tack on another dimension $x^5$, expand the range of the indices to include $5$, using Latin letters, (e.g. $a$, $b$) and enlargen the metric to the form given by the following line element:
$$g_{ab} dx^a dx^b = η_{μν} dx^μ dx^ν + k \left(A_μ dx^μ + dx^5\right)^2.$$

Expand $p_μ$ to $\hat{p}_a$, setting $\hat{p}_5 = e$, defining:
$$\widehat{p}_a = m g_{ab} \frac{dx^b}{ds},$$
and treat all the field variables as being $x^5$-independent. Then, we have:
$$\hat{p}_5 = m k \left(A_ν \frac{dx^ν}{ds} + \frac{dx^5}{ds}\right),\quad
\hat{p}_μ = m \left(η_{μν} + kA_μA_ν\right) \frac{dx^ν}{ds} + m k A_μ \frac{dx^5}{ds} = p_μ + e A_μ.$$

That's what I was referring to by the extra dimension that was "sticking out" - the extra contribution of $e A_μ$ to the total momentum $p_μ + e A_μ$.

Then, we can write:
$$\frac{d\hat{p}_a}{ds} = \frac{∂}{∂x^a}\left(eA_μ\frac{dx^μ}{ds}\right) = e\frac{∂A_μ}{∂x^a}\frac{dx^μ}{ds}.$$
Now, substitute in for $e = \hat{p}_5$:
$$\frac{d\hat{p}_a}{ds} = m k \frac{∂A_μ}{∂x^a}\frac{dx^μ}{ds} \left(A_ν \frac{dx^ν}{ds} + \frac{dx^5}{ds}\right) = \frac{m}2 \frac{∂}{∂x^a}\left(k\left(A_μ\frac{dx^μ}{ds} + \frac{dx^5}{ds}\right)^2\right).$$

Since $η_{μν}$ is $x^a$-independent, we can expand this to include the whole metric:
$$\frac{d\hat{p}_a}{ds} = \frac{m}2 \frac{∂}{∂x^a}\left(η_{μν}\frac{dx^μ}{ds}\frac{dx^ν}{ds} + k\left(A_μ\frac{dx^μ}{ds} + \frac{dx^5}{ds}\right)^2\right) = \frac{m}2 \frac{∂}{∂x^a}\left(g_{bc}\frac{dx^b}{ds}\frac{dx^c}{ds}\right).$$

The coupled equations:
$$\hat{p}_a = m g_{ab} \frac{dx^b}{ds},\quad \frac{d\hat{p}_a}{ds} = \frac{m}2 \frac{∂}{∂x^a}\left(g_{bc}\frac{dx^b}{ds}\frac{dx^c}{ds}\right),
$$
are the momentum-space version of the geodesic law. If you generalize the Minkowski part of the metric $η_{μν}$ to allow for curved space-time backgrounds, then the equations become a union of the geodesic law for 4-dimensional gravity with the Lorentz force law on the curved space-time background.

So, with the inclusion of the extra dimension, and the identification of the charge $e = \hat{p}_5$ as an extra component of momentum for the additional dimension, now you have the Equivalence Principle restored.